# doctrine: is there a way to use associated entity in findBy

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, associations, entity, findby

I have an entity 'employee' which is associated to one or more 'manager' entities.
Therefore i use a join table and an association in the employee entity as follows:

```
/**
* @ManyToMany(targetEntity="manager_entity")
* @JoinTable(name="manager_employees",
* joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="emp_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
* inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="manager_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
* )
*/
protected $managers;
```

this is already working. but now i want to retrieve all employees of a specific manager.
therefore i'm asking if its possible to do something like this:

```
$mgr = $this->em->getRepository ( 'Entities\manager' )->findOneBy ( array (
                "alias" => $this->get('alias'));
// only pseudo code - i know that $managers is a list of managers and $mgr cannot be compared to that
$empList = $this->em->getRepository('Entities\employee')->findBy(array("managers" => $mgr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a function like this to your repository:

```
public function findByManager($managerId)
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->from('employee', 'e')
        ->innerJoin('e.managers m')
        ->where('m.Id = :managerId')
        ->setParameter('managerId', $managerId)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

And then just use:

```
$employee = $repository->findByManager($manager->getId());
```